# Entity Framework Core, count of include too slow compared to T-SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

edit: Removed other include still same result table size 50k rows on ProductAttributes

I got this code, it's running too slowly compared to my T-SQL statement.

```
return _context.ProductAttributes
               .Include(e => e.ProductProductAttributes)
               .Select(x => new GetProductAttributesModel
                                {
                                    Attribute = x,
                                    Count = x.ProductProductAttributes.Count()
                                })
               .ToArrayAsync();
```

Here is the T-SQL statement for comparison:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product_Attribute a 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ctn, AttributeId 
     FROM Product_ProductAttribute 
     GROUP BY AttributeId) d ON d.AttributeId = a.Id
```

How do I get an Entity Framework Core implementation that will be faster or at least similar to the T-SQL statement?

I am hoping that I don't need to do a stored procedure into a select for this... it seems so simple

Comment: What does the query plan show/suggest? Might not be related to LINQ/EF at all. At least I can't see anything immediately wrong with it.

Comment: Entity Framework is designed to **increase** programmer's **productivity** - it's never been designed to be faster than raw SQL (and it cannot be - after all, it's doing a lot more work than a simple T-SQL statement).

Comment: Also your EF query is including two other data sets and your T-SQL is not.

Comment: So this is basically as fast as its going to get for entity here, I am going to have to stored proedure into a select

Comment: @JamieRees that other include is always null at the moment

Comment: Your EF code will always be slower than pure sql.. that's the expected behavior

Comment: The two queries are quite different. The 'Relatives' table isn't even used in your SQL version ...

Comment: You don't need any Inculde() call - Your query can be evaluated SQL side without it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, community consensus that entity will not give me the speed I need for this use case. I will switch to a stored procedure into a select for this case.

Comment: I must ask, is your application feature complete and fully tested functionally? Why are you bothering with performance if you have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: No this is a new feature. That shows usage of an attribute to help users remove unused attributes. The issue is the count is slow. I may even cache/batch this out later if the stored procedure gets too slow.

Comment: I'd bet you can get a similar time out of EF with a little effort, assuming that your result set isn't gigantic. You can log queries using the DbContext.Database.Log callback - maybe try that and see what SQL EF is producing.

Comment: and so it begins.. my life changed when I got a taste of raw sql performance. I suggest you use dapper and nameof(DomainModel.Variable)/ nameof(Database.Table) to maintain intellisense or you will regret next year when you need to change your models or view references